# Why Azure ML , scored probability response greater than 1?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have setup an Azure ML experiment,using "Boosted Decision Tree Regression".

My evaluation results are as follows:

```
"Scored Labels": "N",
"Scored Probabilities": "0.023*************"
```

While testing the deployed web service with data, I am sometimes seeing a scored probability that is greater than 1!

```
"Scored Labels": "N", 
"Scored Probabilities": "1.144*************"
```

As per my understanding, probability of anything can never be grater than 1.
What does a scored probability > 1 in this case mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's related to [`Score Model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/score-model) and up to the type of your used model `Boosted Decision Tree Regression`.

Please refer to the subsection [`Results`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/score-model#results) of the offical document [`Score Model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/score-model), as below.

> The score, or predicted value, can be in many different formats, depending on the model and your input data:
>
> - For classification models, Score Model outputs a predicted value for the class, as well as the probability of the predicted value.
> - For **regression models**, Score Model generates just **the predicted numeric value**.
> - For image classification models, the score might be the class of object in the image, or a Boolean indicating whether a particular feature was found.

So in your case, the `Scored Probabilities` value is just the predicted numeric value, not the probability value.

If you want to get a value between 0 and 1, you can use the [`Normalize Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/normalize-data) Module to change it to a 0-1 scale.